# jq compare using values of same object

Tags: json, jq

I have one json file

a.json:

```
{
  "t": 3
}
{
  "t": 6
}
{
  "t": 13
}
```

And another file

b.json:

```
{
  "t1": 1,
  "t2": 4
}
{
  "t1": 7,
  "t2": 8
}
{
  "t1": 11,
  "t2": 13
}
```

I want to find the t values from a.json, which are between any single range t1, t2 of b.json objects.

So expected output is

```
{
  "t": 3
}
{
  "t": 13
}
```

I have tried
`jq --slurpfile a a.json --slurpfile b b.json -n '$a[] | select(.t >= $b[].t1 and .t <= $b[].t2)'` and
`jq --slurpfile a a.json --slurpfile b b.json -n '$a[] | select(.t == range($b[].t1, $b[].t2))'`, but the comparison does not happen for same object of `$b` and I don't get the expected output.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is oriented to efficiency and also handles the case where the intervals defined by b.json overlap:

```
< a.json jq --slurpfile b b.json '
  def check($value):
    if any(.[]; .t1 <= $value and $value <= .t2) 
    then {t:$value} 
    else empty
    end ;
  . as $a | $b | check($a.t)
'
```

Specifically:

- we use `any` so that the search for an applicable range stops as soon as possible;
- we avoid "slurping" a.json to save RAM;
- we avoid `range` in case any of the ranges is large.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer with explanation. Can you please explain a little more about `< a.json` before `jq` and then taking it in variable `$a`, how this works?

Comment: `< filename jq ...` is much the same as `jq ... filename`; `. as $a` is much the same as assigning the variable $a, in turn, to each separate JSON entity in the input stream.  See the jq manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `jq` filter:

```
jq --slurpfile a a.json --slurpfile b b.json -n \
  '$a[] | [.t] | if inside($b[] | [ range(.t1; .t2+1) ]) then {t:.[]} else empty end'
```

For all values in `a.json`, look if that one is part of the range composed by the arrays of file `b.json`.